# How to position canvas in View.DragShadowBuilder.onProvideShadowMetrics

Tags: android, canvas, drag, shadow

I have a requirement where a draggable view needs the shadow to be initially placed directly on top of the view - that is, it covers the entire view rather than relating to the touch point.

I've been trying all sorts to get this working with my subclass of `View.DragShadowBuilder` but with no luck. I hoped using `drawRect` would allow me to specify the rectangle points so that it would be drawn in the same rectangle as my view, but this results in no canvas being drawn.

However, just using `canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN)` draws the rectangle, but relative to the touch point.

Here is my attempt using `drawRect`:

```
    private class VideoDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

    public VideoDragShadowBuilder(View v) {
        super(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics (Point size, Point touch) {
        int width, height;

        width = getView().getWidth();
        height = getView().getHeight();

        size.set(width, height);
        touch.set(width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setAlpha(45);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);

        canvas.drawRect(getView().getLeft(), getView().getTop(), getView().getRight(), getView().getBottom(), paint);
    }
}
```

Here, the blue rectangle is slightly misaligned with the view underneath because of where I touched - I want it to totally cover the view regardless of where the user touches.

[image]

Comment: post an image with the required result, otherwise its hard to tell what you actually want to achieve

Comment: something like this: http://pastebin.com/3KuF8EmZ ? create this builder for example in onTouchEvent when action is ACTION_DOWN: DragShadowBuilder builder = new DSB(this, event);

Comment: @pskink Thanks for that. It's currently implemented in a onLongClickListener although I can probably change that, however I'm confused as to how the Point is being used in your example other than to set the touch point. Why do you use 8 in the drawRect? I've finally got drawRect to actually draw the rect by using 0 and 0 instead of view.getLeft() and view.getTop() , but it starts at my touch point, not sure how to move it to cover the View so the same problem as with drawColor

Comment: here you have simple TextView http://pastebin.com/ddAFqAQg 8 is used as a 8 pixel padding change it to 0 if you want the CYAN rect to cover the whole View

Comment: @pskink Thank you so much, I've got it working in my project now using your example - the key was setting the touch point. If you want to add this as a proper answer I will mark it correct to give you the credit. Also, I don't really understand why setting the touch point allows the canvas to fully cover the view, is there any good explanation for this? Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up with using @pskink's suggestions. I didn't have to use drawRect at all, the key was setting the touch point which I previously didn't have as I wasn't using onTouchEvent. Adding this for anyone who might have the same problem.

```
private Point lastTouch;

public DraggableFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    dragListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            View.DragShadowBuilder videoShadow = new DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(draggableData, videoShadow, null, 0);
            return true;
        }
    };
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)    {
    lastTouch = new Point((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY()) ;
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

private class DragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

    public VideoDragShadowBuilder(View v) {
        super(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics (Point size, Point touch) {
        super.onProvideShadowMetrics(size, touch);

        // The touch point must be set in order for the canvas to properly fit the view
        if (lastTouch != null) {
            touch.set(lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDrawShadow(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. It doesn't make sense that DnD would function any other way.

Answer (score 1):

> public void drawRect (float left, float top, float right, float
>   bottom, Paint paint) Added in API level 1
>
> Draw the specified Rect using the specified paint. The rectangle will
>   be filled or framed based on the Style in the paint. Parameters left
>     The left side of the rectangle to be drawn top  The top side of the
>   rectangle to be drawn right   The right side of the rectangle to be
>   drawn bottom  The bottom side of the rectangle to be drawn paint  The
>   paint used to draw the rect

Taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRect%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

if you want to call `drawRect` with `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, you should not pass `x2` and `y2` as point coordinates. However, the difference between the end point and the start point yields the desired result, so you should pass `x2 - x1` instead of `x2` and `y2 - y1` instead of `y2`.

Reason: `right` is not a coordinate, but the wideness, `bottom` is not a coordinate, but a height.

Comment: Thanks @Lajos , I've upvoted your answer as it cleared up a big misunderstanding on my part, however after I made suggested change there is still no shadow appearing when I test it. Is there something else I'm missing?

    View view = getView();
         canvas.drawRect(view.getLeft(),view.getTop(), view.getLeft() + view.getWidth(),  view.getTop() + view.getHeight(), paint);